# When is the enclosingMenuItem of an NSView set?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsmenuitem

In writing a custom `NSMenuItem` view, I am accessing the associated `NSMenuItem` via the `NSView` [`enclosingMenuItem` message](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/enclosingMenuItem).  I would like to be able to update some subviews of my custom `NSMenuItem` view just as soon as I know that the enclosing menu item is set, but there is no setter that can be overridden.

Currently I am updating the subviews within an override of `viewWillMoveToWindow:`, but this is causing a problem where, for a brief moment after the menu is opened, the custom view is incorrectly sized. It quickly resizes according to the layout constraints, but the changeover is noticeable and I want to avoid it.